# Split by suffix with Python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, split

I want to split strings only by suffixes. For example, I would like to be able to split `dord word` to `[dor,wor]`.

I though that `\wd` would search for words that end with `d`. However this does not produce the expected results

```
import re
re.split(r'\wd',"dord word")
['do', ' wo', '']
```

How can I split by suffixes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x='dord word'
import re
print re.split(r"d\b",x)
```

or

```
print [i for i in re.split(r"d\b",x) if i] #if you dont want null strings.
```

Try this.

Answer (score 3):

As a better way you can use `re.findall` and use `r'\b(\w+)d\b'` as your regex to find the rest of word before `d`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b(\w+)d\b',s)
['dor', 'wor']
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `\w` also captures digits and underscore, I would define a word consisting of just letters with a `[a-zA-Z]` character class:

```
print [x.group(1) for x in re.finditer(r"\b([a-zA-Z]+)d\b","dord word")]
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/eTNa9f)

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering why your original approach didn't work,

```
re.split(r'\wd',"dord word")
```

It finds all instances of a letter/number/underscore before a "d" and splits on what it finds. So it did this:

do[rd] wo[rd]

and split on the strings in brackets, removing them.

Also note that this could split in the middle of words, so:

```
re.split(r'\wd', "said tendentious")
```

would split the second word in two.